# Avoding repeating a word in pocessive constructions

Tags: sentence-construction, possessives

I have the following sentence:

> Then a dialogue box opens in which the user can specify some distinguishing properties for the anchor using its **text** value or a pattern in the **text**

How can I avoid repeating "text"in the sentence above?

"... a pattern in it" could be an option, is it the only option?!

Comment: _"...using its text value or a pattern therein. "_

Comment: Another reason it feels awkard is because pattern in the text itself is awkward.  I cannot tell if this pattern is within the text being entered or is a pattern for the anchor.  Adding that info would probably give you enough to fix the sentence.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan a pattern in the text of the anchor node. for example `$79.00` is the text of anchor node and it has the patten of a price (a $ sign and a number with two percentage numbers...)

Comment: The original with its repetition was fine. It was clear.

Comment: Is the question: Does a grammatically correct alternative exist? only asking an opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...using the value of or a pattern in the text.